# Python How to convert file data into float data

Tags: python, file, floating-point

I'm trying to convert the data inside a file to be read as float numbers. It is a very large file. It won't let me convert it because it says it is a list. How do I fix this?:

```
    File = open(filename,'r')
    for line in File:
        Data = File.readlines()
        for line in Data:
                numData = float(Data)
    File.close()
```

Comment: You can try `float(line[0])`

Comment: @AbhiP Notice what he's really calling as the parameter. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in Data:
    numData = float(Data)
```

That's where your problem is. You're calling `float()` on the list `Data` instead of on the element `line`.

Incidentally, you seem to be looping twice over the file when you don't have to. You declare `File`, then iterate over it, and for each iteration, you're rereading it -- and iterating over it again. You should probably do something more like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        numData = float(line)
```

Of course, I doubt that you really mean to set `numData` (which should be called `num_data` according to PEP8, IIRC) every time. I don't know what it's meant to be used as, though, because the variable name is unclear, so I can't tell you what you should do instead. If it's a list, you probably mean something like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        num_data.append(float(line))
```

Note that I changed `numData` to `num_data`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
file_lines = [float(ln.rstrip()) for ln in open(filename)]
```